# MvvmCross binaries for alpha/beta channel Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin.ios, mono, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'd like to use MvvmCross with XS on a Mac, and running the beta channel (`Xamarin.iOS 6.3` and `Xamarin.Android 4.7`). Is this currently possible at all? If so are there binaries available somewhere?

Comment: Have you tried the current ones? If so did they not work? If so what did not work? Please provide more details on why and what you are asking.

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I tried. I tried building a sample project that works fine on stable. I got over 30 errors, all of the form `Error CS0518: The predefined type 'System.Object' is not defined or imported (CS0518)`.

Comment: Also, on the _why_, my main reason to use the beta channel is to get F# 3.0 working, which I understand only comes with Mono 3.0, which is only available now on beta/alpha.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the latest Xamarin.Android alpha, which among other things provide PCL support. However the Visual Studio plug-in does not allow for referencing PCL projects into Android project yet. In order to do this you need to manually edit the .csproj file or do it through Xamarin Studio.

You will need to recompile Mvx from source if you want it to work with the new PCL support. There are however some problems with Profile78 PCL's which result in Mvx Core projects not working, more about this in [this thread](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/5507/using-system-linq-expressions-in-a-pcl-method-causes-typeloadexpression-mono-android-4-7-10024) and in this [bugzilla report](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=13081).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't succeed to compile any PCL library, not only MvvmCross
(on Mono 3.0)